# Ajax Template Editor for Reports

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, templates

I have been tasked to create a layout editor for my companies internal Reporting System. The Specifications they gave me indicate that templates must be able to be defined in .html files in a certain folder. These HTML files can have their own style etc. So it's a full HTML page with the html, head and body tag with content areas that are indicated with special a syntax.

Now what's been bothering me is that I have to load this page with it's styling etc. into a layout div (or IFrame maybe?) where I need to be able to work on it with Javascript (Using JQuery) to insert the controls to manage how the data is displayed.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Any ideas as to how achieve this according to specifications? Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to load the page with all referenced stylesheets applied appropriately, and avoiding javascript conflicts is to embed the html in an iframe.

This does however mean that your page will have to be served from the same domain as your application in order for you to be able to interact with the content in an easy way, but as long as this is so (possibly using your app as a proxy for the pages) there is cross browser support out there [from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) * other javascript frameworks are available I'm sure.

Comment: I was thinking this would be the only way. But it just feels a bit dity ? And how compatible is this across the different browsers?

Comment: It will be compatible across all browsers, jQuery offers support for it, there's an example given here - http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: Thx did'nt know that JQuery did that too... What don't they do ? :D . Will try it and report back if I get it working.

Comment: Thanks ended up using the IFrame where I just change the URL and point it to  a url in the service. When I received it I replace all the placeholders onload and bobs you uncle. Thanks for your time.